# How to select sql with if else use column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm beginner for mysql and this my graduation project please help me.

```
//AMOUNT_PEOPLE is variable in nodejs
//place_id is variable in nodejs recieve from front end.
SELECT 
(IF AMOUNT_PEOPLE >= 10
  RETURN COLUMN package_tb.price_group*(AMOUNT_PEOPLE-1)
ELSE IF AMOUNT_PEOPLE >= 6
  RETURN COLUMN package_tb.price_group*(AMOUNT_PEOPLE-1) - (SELECT option_tb.price_group FROM option_tb WHERE obtion_tb.place_id = place_id)
ElSE
  RETURN COLUMN price_normal*AMOUNT_PEOPLE
END IF) AS price,name,detail
FROM package_tb WHERE package_tb.place_id = place_id
```

This ticket booking program
Logic is
Check number of tourist
if tourist >= 10 must use group_price and free 1 person include food for free person option
but if tourist >= 6 must use group_price 
and free 1 person but not include food for free person option
finally tourist 0-5 must use normal_price

Such customer tell me "I want ticket for 10 tourist" the system will check as above explain.

```
package_tb
-package_id
-place_id
-name
-detail
-price_group
-price_normal

option_tb
-option_id
-place_id
-name
-price_group
-price_normal

place_tb
-place_id
-name
```

If tourist use price group option have to use price group only
But tourist use price normal option have to use price normal only.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please provide sample data and explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: What about groups of 3-5 and 7-9? Right now your example shows 0-5 and 7-9 as normal price.

Comment: Apologise I forgot ">"symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) function.
Which is a standard SQL function for switch logic.

Based on the updated question I'm assuming that there can be multiple options per place.

So with node.js variables:

```
SET @place_id = ${PLACE_ID};
SET @amount_people = ${AMOUNT_PEOPLE};
SELECT 
 CASE 
 WHEN @amount_people >= 10 
   THEN (p.price_group * (@amount_people - 1))
 WHEN @amount_people >= 6 
   THEN (p.price_group * (@amount_people - 1)) - SUM(o.price_group)
 ELSE p.price_normal
 END AS price, 
 p.name, 
 p.detail
FROM package_tb p
LEFT JOIN option_tb o ON o.place_id = p.place_id
WHERE p.place_id = @place_id
GROUP BY p.package_id, p.place_id, p.price_normal, p.price_group, p.name, p.detail;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/VVHCD43146)

Comment: I apologised for my asking in the past because question wrong.Now I edited my question please check again please.

Comment: Thanks you very much this easy to understand.

Comment: Nice & thanks. Just a small remark. With this type of logic there's a possibility that the price for amount_people>=10 might become negative, if there's to many options.

Comment: @キキアンマート  Just thought about another thing. Shouldn't it be more correct to calculate >=10 like this : `(p.price_group - SUM(o.price_group))* (@amount_people - 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

--  From which table you want use price_normal? tb or o ???

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN p.AMOUNT_PEOPLE >= 4 
    THEN p.price_group
    WHEN p.AMOUNT_PEOPLE >= 3 
    THEN p.price_group - o.price_food
    ELSE tb.price_normal
    END AS price, 
    p.name, p.detail
FROM package_tb p JOIN option_tb o  ON o.package_id = p.package_id;
```

Comment: I apologised for my asking in the past because question wrong.Now I edited my question please check again please

Answer (score 0):

There are two main control-flow functions in MySQL [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) and [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Since you are not comparing the value of `AMOUNT_PEOPLE` directly, `CASE` is a bit of overkill, which can be simplified slightly by using `IF`.

The syntax for IF is `IF(<expr>, <true_result>, <false_result>)`. This allows you to perform *else if* by chaining another `IF()` as the false_result

```
IF(<expr>, ..., IF(<expr>, ..., ...))
```

Instead of using *else if*, you only need to remove the `option_tb.price_group` when `AMOUNT_PEOPLE` is fewer than 10 to get your desired pricing.

```
/* groups with 6 or more use group price and one person free */
IF(AMOUNT_PEOPLE >= 6, 
    /* groups with fewer than 10 people remove option */
    p.price_group*(AMOUNT_PEOPLE-1) - IF(AMOUNT_PEOPLE < 10, 
       o.price_group, 
       0
    ),
    p.price_normal*AMOUNT_PEOPLE
) AS price
```

This reduces the amount of code slightly, to determine when to subtract a person.

Instead of using a nested sub-query, which would be executed for each row returned. If the `option_tb.place_id` is unique, a `JOIN` would be more preferable.

If `option_tb.place_id` is not unique, you would need to use a `GROUP BY`. One approach is to `JOIN` using a sub-query, to avoid false matching on the join table groupings.

To ensure results are not excluded when a row in the `option_tb` table fails to match a `place_id`, you would use a `LEFT JOIN` that returns `NULL` instead of excluding the row.

Then you can use [`COALESE(<column>, 0)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to retrieve the value from the column or 0 if the column value is `NULL`.

---

In NodeJS you can use `${var}` to inject a variable into a string.

For example:

```
var place_id = 1;
var query = 'SELECT ${place_id};';
console.log(query);
```

Results in

```
SELECT 1;
```

---

**Putting it all together.**

### Example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9sWYN1MKMKrGQD6KMkZuLM/3)

```
SELECT 
IF(${AMOUNT_PEOPLE} >= 6, 
    p.price_group*(${AMOUNT_PEOPLE}-1) - IF(${AMOUNT_PEOPLE} < 10, COALESCE(o.price_group, 0), 0),
    p.price_normal*${AMOUNT_PEOPLE}
) AS price,
p.name,
p.detail
FROM package_tb AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       place_id, 
       SUM(price_group) AS price_group
    FROM option_tb
    GROUP BY place_id
) AS o
ON o.place_id = p.place_id
WHERE p.place_id = ${place_id};
```

Comment: Thank you for answer for my question wrong. But you made me apply to many other things. :)

Comment: @キキアンマート I presume that is because the `option_tb.place_id` is not unique. Updated with fixed 6 or more, an example of new usage and explanation.